# Setting or disabling initial animation

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I'm setting a `Counter` on a page and need it to start at a particular value and then countdown, but FlipClock.js insists on doing an initial animation, seemingly whenever a digit starts as a `0`, it starts it as a `9` instead and flips over to `0`, and it looks dumb in my context:

For example, when you do this:

```
clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 20, {
    clockFace: 'Counter'
});
```

It will initially appear as `19` and then flip up to `20`, which, since I intend to count it down, looks really weird. Visually it then goes:

19, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, ...

Which is jarring. It looks like it's gonna count up, and instead it counts down. Is there a way to make it *not* do that?

Example:

Note, this is an older version of the library (0.7.8) not the latest (0.8.0) and it behaves a little differently. It doesn't flip from 19 to 20, but from 20 to 20, which still looks odd and also the animation is way worse looking in this version, but it demonstrates the problem:

```js
clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 20, {
  clockFace: 'Counter',
  countdown: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<div class="clock"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the hacky way I got around this problem was to set a class on the `div` element with:

```
.wrapTimer {
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Then only when I'm ready for the clock to start counting down, I remove the class causing the timer to appear already displaying 20. Simply hiding and showing the element doesn't work because it won't animate until it's visible.

This worked in Chrome at least, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

http://flipclockjs.com/faces/counter says you need to decrement yourself

```js
var clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 20, {
  clockFace: 'Counter'
});
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".wrap").show();
  setInterval(function() {
    clock.decrement();
  }, 1000);
},1000);
```

```css
.wrap { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="clock"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not a counter, it's using the default `clockFace` and auto-starting. If you use `clockFace: 'counter'` it does not work. Although, interestingly, with version 0.7.8 it flips from 20 to 20 instead of 19 to 20 (which happens in 0.8.0, the latest version)

Comment: That's still not the problem. I can decrement it just fine. The problem is when you initially start it. When you click "Run code snippet" notice the unwanted initial animation on `20`. For some reason, with the older version, it at least goes starts at 20 and then there's a flip that leaves it at 20. But the older version looks terrible anyway. I want to get rid of that flip that shows as soon as you initialize the counter.

Comment: Then you need to talk to the developer. The snippet above shows a rendering animation on 20, but does not do 19, 20, 19

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. The project hasn't been updated in 2 years, so I suspect I should just find an alternative library or else just live with it. Which is disappointing.